# Почему нельзя использовать auto, extern, register в классах С++?

Tags: c++, ооп, классы, память

```
class point
{
    public:
        register int x; //Выдает ошибку "storage class specified for 'x'"
};
```

Такую же ошибку выдает, если применить к переменной x спецификаторы классов памяти `auto`, `extern`. А вот со `static` все нормально.
Искал причину в интернете, но так и не нашел. Можете мне объяснить, почему так происходит?

Comment: auto уже поменяло свое значение. extern влияет на линковку, register тоже уже не используется. Это я к тому, что даже если бы оно работало раньше, сейчас оно уже всё равно отвалилось бы.

Comment: Ну во-превых, `register` уже давно исключен из языка. А `auto` уже давно потеряло свой первоначальный смысл и приобрело новый, никак не с ним не связанный.

Answer (score 5):

1. `register` — это указание на хранение переменной в регистре процессора. Как вы собираетесь хранить там долгоживущее поле класса?
2. `auto` — до C++11 то же. После — указывается вместо типа и предписывает компилятору вывести этот самый тип самостоятельно, на основе типа присваиваемого значения. А у вас в объявлении поля класса такого нет.
3. `extern` — указывает, что данная сущность реализована в другом `.cpp`-файле. В случае функций это бессмысленно (у них для подобного есть прототипы). В случае же класса это бессмысленно вдвойне (класс — это уже один большой прототип методов).
4. А `static` работает потому, что приобретает совершенно другой смысл. Вне класса это запрет на экспорт функции из `.cpp`-файла. В классе же это ключевое слово предписывает не использовать неявный `this` в прототипе данной функции.

Answer (score 1):

У вас смешаны в одну кучу совершенно разные понятия: класс памяти (storage class), тип линковки (linkage) и дедукция типов.

Бывший storage class `register` уже навсегда удален из языка. Слово остается ключевым, но не используется. В любом случае, этот storage class имеет смысл только в *определении* объекта. Объявление поля класса определением не является. Более того, С++ изначально разрешал использование этого storage class только с "короткоживущими", т.е. *локальными* объектами. (То же самое относится и к ключевому слову `auto` в его изначальном значении.)

Ключевое слово `extern` предназначено в первую очередь для управления linkage и указывать его имеет смысл только при ссылке на сущности, живущие в namespace scope, т.е., выражаясь практическим языком, сущности, способные породить экспортируемые/импортируемые символы в объектном файле - глобальные переменные и функции. Нестатическое поле класса таковым не является.

Ключевое слово `auto` в языке С++ уже давно не является спецификатором storage class, а обозначает дедуцируемый тип в объявлении. Дедукция типов для нестатических полей класса в С++ не поддерживается.

Ключевое слово `static` в контексте объявления члена класса имеет свой, особый смысл, мало связанный со значением этого ключевого слова в других контекстах. Именно ради этого особого смысла оно и поддерживается в объявлениях членов класса.